# FME SpatialFilter not outputting desired results

Tags: fme-form

Have this workflow that pretty much starts with a mapinfo table with either a point feature or a polygon feature that identifies land, licences, and leases, gets filtered based on feature type.  From here all points go to the spatial filter to be compared against a property layer and merge these attributes together.  I have this issue where some points are within the same polygon but the attributes are different (Ie; Local gov leasing an area from another authority and then subleasing to a community group therefore some attributes are different), and I want to replicate this showing two separate property polygon features.  You can see that 715 features go into the spatial filter and 708 come out.

For some background, this is a property register and I use points to get the property information since this comes from a state authority and they increase the accuracy of parcels when they receive more accurate information, so I have gone this method to be more dynamic so the boundaries in our land register change with the States Authority.  After I figure this i want to be able to compare "todays date" (when it gets run) with the expiry of leases and licences and email me so we know when they fall due for renewing. [image: workflow]

Comment: Just a quick comment. You could probably use the GeometryFilter in place of that first AttributeFilter. That would be the standard transformer to use - although I think what you're doing will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other solution would be a PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer I think. As mentioned for the SpatialRelator, you define a list name and then explode that list.

The PointOnAreaOverlayer has output ports for both the points and the areas, so you can use both outputs if you wish.

There's also a tutorial (demo and video) available on [the FME knowledge base](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/33912/point-in-polygon-calculations-with-the-pointonarea.html) that might help.

Answer (score 5):

The SpatialFilter in FME cannot relate more than one feature per candidate. You need the SpatialRelator to handle these. This transformer can create a list of all points that touched a polygon, and then you can explode that list which should give you 715 polygons containing all the merged attributes.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more.  I have implemented the SpatialRelator and have the points going into the Requestor port and property polygons going into the supplier.  I get the 715 output into a ListExploder and explode the list name and points are still produced.  I am missing something about the SpatialRelator

Comment: Try switching it round so that Polygon features are the requesters and Point features are the suppliers - the suppliers are the features holding attribution you want to attach to the requesters, so points are your suppliers

Comment: I have the issue that some of the polygon features are created correctly through my process and I can trace these polygons all the way to just prior to the MapInfo output with the FME inspector.  But once the file is outputted into the MapInfo file the polygon just turns into a "bounding box" type scenario for that polygon (and has the correct attribute data).